Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig: ... (problem with Emacs)
I'm trying to configure Emacs and it seems like I'm stumbling on every step so far. Currently I'm trying to install/setup the Melpa package but it gives me back the usual error message:
Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig:
No public key for 645357D2883A0966 created at 2024-04-24T11:10:05+0200 using EDDSA
Command output:
gpg: Signature made Mi 24 Apr 2024 11:10:05 CEST
gpg:                using EDDSA key 0327BE68D64D9A1A66859F15645357D2883A0966
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key

From what I've seen in the answers on threads for my issue I need to update to the new key via https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/gnu-elpa-keyring-update.html but I'm at a loss for how to actually do that and the usual response to this is to copy + paste "gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40" into the terminal. I did try this with some hesitation, since I think I'm only just copy-pasting an old key (066DAFCB81E42C40) that doesn't serve any purpose at this point. I don't know how to find the currently used key.
Long story short, I'd appreciate it if someone could help me with this or at the very least guide me in the right direction.
P.S. I use the latest version of Ubuntu. (22.04)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

try (setopt package-check-signature nil)

I have the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04. Did you find a solution? Try with the new signature ?
gpg --homedir ~/.config/emacs/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 645357D2883A0966
I only get gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data

The solution could be found on the mailing list:
https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2024-05/msg00248.html

Disable signature verification by setting package-check-signature to nil with set-variable
package-list-packages, install gnu-elpa-keyring-update (my local list only contained version 2022.12, which could not be downloaded anymore. disabling package signatures allowed me to install the current 2022.12.1).
Re-enable package signature checks or restart emacs.


This only partially works for me. If i try to install eglot, i get an error that says "Failed to verify signature external-completion-0.1.tar.sig:" then the good signature of the expired key, then the good signature of the new key with the warning "This key is not certified with a trusted signature! There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner."

This is only an issue in emacs before 27.
I fixed this by removing gnu-elpa-keyring-update after restarting emacs to make sure that the new key is imported and then deleting the old key via gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/ --delete-keys C433554766D3DDC64221BFAA066DAFCB81E42C40 so that emacs no longer checks the old signature.
See https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2024-06/msg00012.html for the source of the information of duplicate checking.

Apparently the other thing i tried worked and not this, but i confirmed on my laptop another simpler way: If you replace the file with the keys in the distribution package, on my linux mint (so probably also on ubuntu and debian) it is /usr/share/emacs/26.3/etc/package-keyring.gpg, with an export that does not contain the 2019 key, emacs won't readd the key to the keyring in the .emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/ dir.
This way works on my laptop now.
